# How to use different kinds of placeholders in enum classes

Tags: android, kotlin, enums, android-jetpack-compose

Is it possible within an enum class to enable it for different kinds of placeholders? I want to use 1 item that has 1 placeholder, then another item that has 2 placeholders. The current code I have seems to only allow me to use 1 placeholder.

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="size_placeholder">Size %1$d</string>
<string name="sizes_placeholder_and_placeholder">Sizes %1$d and %2$d</string>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
enum class Clothes(@StringRes val nameId: Int, val sizeId: Int, val onePlaceholder: Int, val twoPlaceholders: Int) {
    ItemA(R.string.item_a, R.string.size_placeholder, 8),
    ItemB(R.string.item_B, R.string.sizes_placeholder_and_placeholder, 0, 2);
}
...

LazyColumn(
    state = listState,
    modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        .padding(it)
) {
    items(items) {
        Column() {
            Text(text = stringResource(id = it.nameId))
            Text(text = stringResource(id = it.sizeId, it.onePlaceholder, it.twoPlaceholders))
        }
    }
}
```

**Expected result**

[image]

Comment: As I pointed out previously, [`stringResource()` takes a `vararg` of format arguments](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/res/package-summary#stringResource(kotlin.Int,kotlin.Array)). [Here is the source code for it](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:compose/ui/ui/src/androidMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/res/StringResources.android.kt;l=51-54;drc=d177cf4915e25b3879d0d2b55952197902dd73b5). So, what did you try for using two format args, and what was your specific problem with it?

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried changing `val onePlaceholder: Int` to `val onePlaceholder: Any` then used "`(2, 8)`" as the placeholder but that didn't work

Comment: Did you try `stringResource(id = it.sizeId, it.onePlaceholder, it.twoPlaceholders)`?

Comment: @CommonsWare I've updated my code. Is it heading in the right direction?

Comment: "Is it heading in the right direction?" -- I don't think so. What I suggested in my previous comment is still my suggestion, as that is what works and is what is documented. Make sure that you have `import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource` and that you are not pulling in some other `stringResource()` top-level function.

Comment: Answered here: [How to use sealed class for placeholder values in string resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72638165/how-to-use-sealed-class-for-placeholder-values-in-string-resource)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you wanted to define a specific groupings of a some type and have them some distinction from each other.

Regardless, I would approach this with `sealed classes` or a simple object of a class with varying arguments `varargs` of placeholder strings.

```
sealed class Clothes {
  data class FixedSizeClothing(val size: String, val placeholder: String): Clothes()

  data class MultiSizeClothing(val sizes: List<String>, val placeholders: 
  List<String>): Clothes()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`stringResource()` takes a `vararg` for placeholder values. So, you use:

```kotlin
stringResource(id = it.sizeId, it.onePlaceholder, it.twoPlaceholders)
```

For example, I created a scrap project in Android Studio Chipmunk, using the Empty Compose Activity template. I set up `strings.xml` to be:

```xml
<resources>
  <string name="app_name">My Application</string>
  <string name="size_placeholder">Size %1$d</string>
  <string name="sizes_placeholder_and_placeholder">Sizes %1$d and %2$d</string>
  <string name="item_a">Item A</string>
  <string name="item_B">Item B</string>

</resources>
```

And I set up `MainActivity.kt` to be:

```kotlin
package com.commonsware.myapplication

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.annotation.StringRes
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.rememberLazyListState
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.commonsware.myapplication.ui.theme.MyApplicationTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    Content()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

enum class Clothes(@StringRes val nameId: Int, val sizeId: Int, val onePlaceholder: Int, val twoPlaceholders: Int) {
    ItemA(R.string.item_a, R.string.size_placeholder, 8, 1337),
    ItemB(R.string.item_B, R.string.sizes_placeholder_and_placeholder, 0, 2);
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun Content() {
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    LazyColumn(
        state = listState
    ) {
        items(listOf(Clothes.ItemA, Clothes.ItemB)) {
            Column {
                Text(text = stringResource(id = it.nameId))
                Text(text = stringResource(id = it.sizeId, it.onePlaceholder, it.twoPlaceholders))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result, while lacking your desired formatting, matches the desired content:

[image: Output of above composable]

Comment: Item A did confuse me simply because I didn't need a 2nd placeholder but your explanation made the situation clearer. Can `1337` be set to `null` or `0` as it is not needed for showing on screen?

Comment: @wbk727: "I didn't need a 2nd placeholder" -- your `enum class` says that you do. Perhaps you should not be using an `enum class` here. "Can 1337 be set to null or 0 as it is not needed for showing on screen?" -- so long as it fits the data type requested by your `enum class` constructor, it can be whatever you want. You have it declared as `Int`, so it cannot be `null`, but it could be `0` or `1337` or whatever other `Int` that you like.