# How to use sealed class data to display alphabet index scroller

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

After creating a sealed class for my `LazyColumn`,  how can I use the inital of every item for an alphabet scroller? `it.?` is where my problem occurs as for some reason, it does not let me accesss my sealed class and use it, i.e. `itemName`.

```
sealed class Clothes {
    data class FixedSizeClothing(val itemName: Int, val sizePlaceholder: Int): Clothes()

    data class MultiSizeClothing(val itemName: Int, val sizePlaceholders:
    List<Int>): Clothes()
}

val clothingItems = remember { listOf(
        Clothes.FixedSizeClothing(itemName = R.string.jumper, itemPlaceholder = 8),
        Clothes.MultiSizeClothing(itemName = R.string.dress, itemPlaceholders = listOf(0, 2))
    )
}

val headers = remember { clothingItems.map { getString(it.?).first().uppercase() }.toSet().toList() }

val listState = rememberLazyListState()
LazyColumn(
    state = listState,
    modifier = Modifier
        .weight(1f)
        .padding(it)
) {
    items(clothingItems) {
        val text1 = when (it) {
            is Clothes.FixedSizeClothing ->
                stringResource(id = it.itemName)
            is Clothes.MultiSizeClothing ->
                stringResource(id = it.itemName)
        }

        val text2 = when (it) {
            is Clothes.FixedSizeClothing ->
                stringResource(id = R.string.size_placeholder, it.sizePlaceholder)
            is Clothes.MultiSizeClothing ->
                stringResource(id = R.string.size_placeholder_and_placeholder, it.itemPlaceholders[0], it.itemPlaceholders[1])
        }

        Column(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable {}) {...}
    }
}

val offsets = remember { mutableStateMapOf<Int, Float>() }
var selectedHeaderIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

fun updateSelectedIndexIfNeeded(offset: Float) {
    val index = offsets
        .mapValues { abs(it.value - offset) }
        .entries
        .minByOrNull { it.value }
        ?.key ?: return
    if (selectedHeaderIndex == index) return
    selectedHeaderIndex = index
    val selectedItemIndex = clothingItems.indexOfFirst { getString(it.?).first().uppercase() == headers[selectedHeaderIndex] }
    scope.launch {
        listState.scrollToItem(selectedItemIndex)
    }
}

Column(
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .background(Color.Gray)
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures {
                updateSelectedIndexIfNeeded(it.y)
            }
        }
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectVerticalDragGestures { change, _ ->
                updateSelectedIndexIfNeeded(change.position.y)
            }
        }
) {
    headers.forEachIndexed { i, header ->
        Text(
            header,
            modifier = Modifier
                .onGloballyPositioned {
                    offsets[i] = it.boundsInParent().center.y
                },
            color = Color.White
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: To access it you have to determine which type you are dealing with first, the same as I explained in the other answer to your other question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72640904/2422224.
What you could do, however, is define the `val itemName: Int` in the parent `Clothes` class. Then you would not need to use a `when` expression to get just the `itemName` property.

Comment: Would `val itemName: Int` need to be initialized? Something like `val itemName: Int = 0` in the parent class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the `val itemName: Int` in the parent `Clothes` class and override it in you other subclasses. If you do that, you then do not need to use a `when` expression if you just want to access the `itemName` property.

The parent class can be a sealed interface instead of a sealed class. That way it is a bit more flexible and a bit less verbose when overriding its properties. Also `: Clothes()` then becomes just `: Clothes`

```
sealed interface Clothes {
    val itemName: Int

    data class FixedSizeClothing(override val itemName: Int, val sizePlaceholder: Int): Clothes
    data class MultiSizeClothing(override val itemName: Int, val sizePlaceholders: List<Int>): Clothes
}
```

And the line where you create the headers becomes

```
val headers = clothingItems.map { stringResource(it.itemName).first().uppercase() }.toSet().toList()
```

The `remember {}` does not make much sense because if your data changes so can the set of initial letters. You also cannot use the `stringResouce()` function inside `remember {}`, because `stringResouce()` has to be used inside a @Composable function.

There is a different way of obtaining Resources and then using `resources.getString(...)` if you would like to retrieve resource strings inside a `remember {}` block. But in this case the `remember {}` block does not make sense due to the data potentially changing. The optimization to cache initial letters would have to be done in a different way.